# Copy or reference when accessing row vectors of Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, performance, reference, eigen

I'm working with code that uses the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) matrix library. I've noticed that all through that code, there are accessors as follows:

```
RowVector3f V(size_t vertex_index) const
{
    return mymatrix.row(vertex_index);
}
```

Wouldn't it be better to use an accessor that returns a const ref? Is that possible with Eigen? Or maybe just return the pointer to internal float to the row-begin and cast it to a vector (of course assuming matching row-major layout)?

Comment: If you are worried about performance then don't. Try it out first. There are enough people using Eigen to make sure it's fast enough. Plus you don't know how the vectors are implemented. They might just be shallow copies or just typedefs to ptr in memory anyway.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. I don't know. That enough people use it so I shouldn't worry might be true, but I'd still like to have a technical answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eigen, mymatrix.row(vertex_index) returns a Block (assuming mymatrix is a Matrix3f). A Block object is essentially a pointer to the original data. In your case, this proxy is copied into a RowVector3f. Fortunately, for such small fixed size objects, the compiler will easily optimize away this extra copy. So I'd not bother.

In a more general case, I'd rewrite the V method to return a MatrixXf::RowXpr (which is a proper typedef to Block<...>).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this library, but I did use that techinique, namely, return objects, and return them by value and not by reference. This is for security - you can't change the original data when you return a portion of it by value.

Also, using objects instead of pointers to data make the code more syntax-friendly and high level.

Comment: You can't change a `const &` either.