# Is it possible to get the reference of a row of a Matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have the following code which uses Eigen C++ Library.

```
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixXf& myrow)
{

  myrow.setOnes();
}



int main()
{


  Eigen::MatrixXf A(2,3);
  Eigen::MatrixXf tmp1(1,3);
  myFunc(tmp1);
  A.row(1) = tmp1;
  std::cout<<"A is..\n"<<A<<std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

As you can see, to manipulate the rows of the Matrix A, I used a temporary variable "tmp1". Is it possible to do it without using any temporary variable? I do not want to pass the entire matrix "A" to the function, as a parameter. Please note that, "myFunc" is merely an example, I may have to do some complicated things inside the function to manipulate the rows of "A". Please also note that I, some times, I would like to call "myFun" as given in the example. So I need a solution which will work in both the cases.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13915065/951890

Comment: Any reason not to use `Eigen::Ref<VectorXf>` ?

Answer (score 5):

Eigen supports block expressions that reference a submatrix in a given matrix. You can pass this block directly to your function:

```
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixXf::RowXpr myrow)
{
    myrow.setOnes();
}

...
myFunc(A.row(1));
```

The block expression is [Block](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. It solves the problem I posted. But, now the example code I posted, gives compilation error. The problem is that,  "myFunc" expects a reference now.  Some times, I would like to call "myFun" as given in the example. Please see my edited post.

Comment: You can still pass `tmp1.row(0)`. You could also define an overload for a general 1-row matrix that does this for you. Or go with a template as Avi suggested.

Comment: @Avi Yes, tmp1.row(0) is always an option. I think I got a better one, improvising Avi's reply. Please check it and comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can template the function in [Nico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831962/2899559) as folows:

```
template<typename Derived>
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m)
{
    m.setOnes();
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf A(2, 3);
    Eigen::MatrixXf tmp1(1, 3);
    myFunc(tmp1);
    A.row(1) = tmp1;
    std::cout << "A is..\n" << A << std::endl;

    myFunc(A.row(0));
    std::cout << "A is..\n" << A << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nico Compilation Error for myFunc(A.row(0)); error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false> >&' from an rvalue of type 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >::RowXpr {aka Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>}'
     myFunc(A.row(0));
                    ^
test.cpp:19:6: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&) [with Derived = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>]'
 void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m)

Comment: You're correct. I tested it on VS2015 and due to a non-standard binding r-value to l-value reference it worked. Fails with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Improvising Avi's reply, I got the following code working. Actually we are fooling compiler and removing the "const" inside "myFunc". I am not sure whether it is a clean method and also not sure about any performance price for this method.

```
template<typename Derived>
void myFunc(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> const& m)
{
    Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m_dummy = const_cast<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& > (m);
    m_dummy.setOnes();
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf A(2, 3);
    Eigen::MatrixXf tmp1(1, 3);
    myFunc(tmp1);
    A.row(1) = tmp1;
    std::cout << "A is..\n" << A << std::endl;

    myFunc(A.row(0));
    std::cout << "A is..\n" << A << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Your signature promises the caller to not change `m`, but you actually do. If you want to modify `m`, then don't pass it as `const`. Never use `const_cast` unless you really know what you are doing. That's exactly what Avi did in his answer

Comment: @Nico Yes, I agree with you. However, just now I found that Eigen Documentation suggests such a method. Please refer [Eigen_Doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) & comment. Please also note that Avi's answer results in compilation error.

Comment: Well, that's just awful. The better way would be to copy things to the temporary matrix. Anyway, the scenario in the Eigen doc is different from yours. In your case, casting is not necessary.

Comment: Here, the main objective is to avoid temporary objects!

Comment: That's why const-casting is not necessary in your case!